# Function to compare arrays in Vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to write a function for UFT in vbscript which compare two arrays and makes sure all the values in the both arrays are an exact match.
However, the order of the values could be inconsistent.

```
 Function CompareArrays(array1, array2)

   Dim i,j
   Dim arrkeys1,arrKeys2
   arrkeys1 = array1.keys
   arrkeys2 = array2.keys

  'Do they have the same number of items?
   If array1.Count <> array2.Count Then
    CompareArrays = False
    Exit Function
   End If

  'Compare keys and values

  For i = 0 To UBound(arrKeys2)

      If Not array2.Exists(arrKeys1(i)) Then
     'array1 has a key which array2 doesn't have  
      CompareArrays = False
      Exit Function         
      End If

        For j  = 0 To Ubound(arrkeys1)

          If array1(i) <> array2(j)  Then
            print "Value"& array1(i) " not found in current position" 
            CompareArrays = False
            Else 
            print "Value Found"
            CompareArrays =True
          End If
        Next'j 
  Next 'i 

  End Function
```

I think there might be a problem with the logic of this script somewhere.
And I am getting no output at all.
The function should just return CompareArrays are True or False.
Example of arrays to be compared :

```
dim Array1
set Array1=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Array1.Add "Tom", "20"
Array1.Add "Rob", "20"
Array1.Add "Harry", "40"

dim Array2
set Array2=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Array2.Add "Rob", "20"
Array2.Add "Tom", "20"
Array2.Add "Harry", "40"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example online, I hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBScript, Array is not an object which has the Keys/Exists/Count method.

I think you are actually trying to compare 2 dictionary objects which stores keys and values.

Below script will compare the dictionary.

```
 Function CompareArrays(array1, array2)

        'Do they have the same number of items?
        If array1.Count <> array2.Count Then
            CompareArrays = False
            Exit Function
        End If

        'Compare keys and values
        For Each Key in array1.Keys

                'Check Keys
                If NOT(array2.Exists(Key)) Then
                    CompareArrays = False
                    Exit Function
                End If

                'Check Value
                If array1.Item(Key) <> array2.Item(Key) Then
                    CompareArrays = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
        Next

        CompareArrays = True

  End Function
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dighate, I am not checking any order! For your input, I am getting 'True' as output. Check again.

Comment: It turns out, UFT Ide did not recognize For each "key" in array.keys  statement. But, when I defined key as key = array1.keys it worked. This worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to order both arrays before do the comparison, I don't have a visual basic editor but this may work:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        dim a1 as Array = {1,2,3}
        dim a2 as Array = {3,2,1}
        dim result = CompareArrays(a1,a2)
        Console.WriteLine("comparison = " & result)

        dim a3 as Array ={"a","b","c"}
        dim a4 as Array = {"b","c","h"}

        result = CompareArrays(a3,a4)
        Console.WriteLine("comparison = " & result)

    End Sub

    Function CompareArrays(array1, array2) as Boolean
        Console.WriteLine(array1)

        If array1.Length <> array2.Length Then
            return false
        End If
       Array.Sort(array1)
       Array.Sort(array2)

        For i as integer = 0 To UBound(array1)
           if(array1(i) <> array2(i))
            return false
           End If
        Next
    return true
    End Function


End Module
```

---

```
output:
comparison = True
comparison = False
```

I found a vb online compiler this is the example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/uI1Mp4

Comment: It wont. It is VB.Net. array is not an object in VBScript.

Comment: I updated my answer I found a  online VB editor, hope that helps